# Javascript Parse URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, url

I want to parse the #!/ url fragment with Javascript/jQuery, like...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/#!/home
```

will load

```
http://www.mydomain.com/home
```

Thanks!

Comment: Simply split the `url` using `#` and then load the `0` index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( location.hash.charAt(1) == "!") location.href = location.hash.substr(2);
```

However, this is a redirect, which somewhat defeats the purpose of `#!` in the first place.

That said, replace `location.href` with a local variable and you can use it to make an AJAX call, like you're supposed to if you're using that construct.

Comment: How do I replace the `location.href` with a AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your pattern by a void string

```
var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/#!/home";
url = url.replace("#!/","");
alert(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your url:

```
var url= "http://www.mydomain.com/#!/home" // window.location.href
var newUrl = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('#'))+url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
location.replace(newUrl);
```